# onStateChanged() and onSlide() methods are called forever when bottomsheet state changes in Android

Tags: android, material-design, bottom-sheet

I developed a bottom sheet with the source codes shown below. However, when i change state of bottom sheet(by changing its state collapsed, expanded, or hide) onStateChanged and onSlide method is called forever. I don't understand why. Is this behaviour normal?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="24dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button 1"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:text="Button 2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:text="Button 3"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/ipsum"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheetBehavior;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View bottomSheet = findViewById( R.id.bottom_sheet );
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button_1 );
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button_2 );
        Button button3 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button_3 );

        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);

        mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        mBottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(true);
        mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(300);
        //mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);

        mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onStateChanged() is called.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // this method is called forever i dont understand why???
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onStateChanged() is called. in onSlide()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // this method is also called forever i dont understand why???
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch( v.getId() ) {
            case R.id.button_1: {
                mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.button_2: {
                mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.button_3: {
                mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```